# Database Mapping World Cities to Metropolitan Statistical Areas (and non-US MSA equivalents)

Tags: python, csv, geocoding, geography, google-ads-api

My problem is that I have a file with thousands of cities and I want to map city names to  ([Metropolitan Statistical Areas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metropolitan_Statistical_Area) and the MSA equivalent for non-US cities.  There have been a bunch of posts here on similar questions.  I'm using Python if that helps (ie in case there is a python package available similar to how the googlemaps python package works...)

1. [Mapping Cities to Zip Codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6588890/whats-the-best-way-to-lookup-the-us-county-a-us-city-resides-in).  There is a good answer here that provides a csv with zip codes for every city in the US.  But because the census data is published mapping US counties to MSA's, instead of US cities, I would still need to find a way to map back from zip codes to US cities.
2. [Database of US Cities to MSA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1446259/database-of-us-metropolitan-area-names) This is essentially my question (at least the US portion), but it was not answered to the satisfaction of the poster, or my question.
3. [Google's Geocoding Developer Site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2708276/cities-to-metropolitan-areas) The Google Geocoding developer's site has a useful CSV that has some US cities mapped to a Google Metro Region code.  The problem is that it is not MSA.  The old Google csv, [downloadable here](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/metrocodes?hl=iw-IL) does not say how the metro coding system was created.  The [site](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/metrocodes?hl=iw-IL) also has a link to the new Google coding system based on Nielsen's DMA (designated market area) coding system.

I'm really just looking for a csv file that has city, state (if US), country, region code.  Where region code is based on well-regarded standard (the US Census Bureau's MSA would be ideal for US cities, and having non-US country's census classifications for non-US cities would be ideal too).  Does such a file exist?  Alternatively, is there a python package that connects to some database such that I run my script on my input file and it outputs the corresponding region code?

Thanks very much!

**ANSWER**

For anyone interested, here is a pretty good file that maps US cities to counties: http://www.census.gov/statab/ccdb/ccdbcityplace.html

Answer (score 2):

I was on the hunt for a similar MSA-level resource and discovered this map at the CartoDB website: https://common-data.cartodb.com/tables/cb_2013_us_cbsa_5m/public/map

[image]

You can download several different formats, including GeoJSON and CSV. Here's a screenshot that shows the type and values of the data exported in CSV (since that was the original poster's requirement):

[image]

I hope this is helpful to others who come across this post!